# Group pixels in an Image array, in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tuples

I have a numpy array - from an image - in this shape:

```
    Arr = 
    array([[[ 61,  61,  61],
    [ 60,  60,  60],
    [ 60,  60,  60],
    ..., 
    [203, 203, 203],
    [201, 201, 201],
    [199, 199, 199]],
     .
     .
     .    

   [[204, 204, 204],
    [204, 204, 204],
    [204, 204, 204],
    ..., 
    [205, 205, 205],
    [206, 206, 206],
    [207, 207, 207]]], dtype=uint8)
```

I want to work with this array in "tuples" of varying length e.g. 5 (and not just the current 3):

```
    array([[[ 61,  61,  61, 60, 60],
    [ 60,  60,  60, 60, 60],
    .
    .
    .
```

Function tuple() seem to be for lists and in any case it does not offer the option to determine the length of a group of pixels. I have also tried using zip(), thus:

```
    newArr = zip(*[Arr[i::n] for i in range(n)]). For n=5, it gives:
    newArr = 
    [(array([[ 61,  61,  61],
     [ 60,  60,  60],
     [ 60,  60,  60],
     ..., 
     [203, 203, 203],
     [201, 201, 201],
     [199, 199, 199]], dtype=uint8), array([[ 63,  63,  63],
     [ 62,  62,  62],
     [ 62,  62,  62],
     .
     .
     .
      [207, 207, 207],
     [209, 209, 209],
     [210, 210, 210]], dtype=uint8), array([[204, 204, 204],
     [204, 204, 204],
     [205, 205, 205],
     ..., 
     [206, 206, 206],
     [207, 207, 207],
     [208, 208, 208]], dtype=uint8))]
```

Any way out of this? Here is the image: [image: image used in this case]

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the values are grouped in threes is because those are the values of the color channels, either RGB, HSV or whatever the format is. Each pixel has three values, that is why you cant group them any other way. You could convert the image to grayscale with:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = Image.open('imagename')
img2 = img.convert('L')
img2_array = np.asarray(img2).copy()
```

That will change the value of each pixel to a single integer (0-255) and leave you with an array with the dimensions of the image itself.

**EDIT:**
To segment the image into five pixel groups:

```
seg = 5
img2_array = img2_array.tolist()
img_grouped = np.array([img2_array[0][x:x+seg] for x in range(0,len(img2_array),seg)])
```

Comment: Well, and how can I change the grouping in the grayscale then?

Comment: You want to group them in five pixel units? Can you explain the reasoning behind this?

Comment: See edited answer. That gets you where you want, though I am still curious as to the why.

Comment: @Gareth Sure, this got me what I wanted. As for the reasoning, I wanted to alter the input features to a self-organising map neural network and study the effect of the output. It works with the original 3, but not when the grouping is changed to 4,5 etc. Thank you.

Comment: @Gathide Sounds interesting. Would love to read an in depth description of that and see it in action. Do you have a website or blog where you document your efforts?